# How to change the language of application in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application, in which i am giving user to select other language , by default the application will be in English , if user selects other language from the list.
The application language should be get changed to the respective language.
I know the concept of Localization, but if there any way to do that, 
if i want to do that using localization please suggest me proper steps for that.
please suggest me solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, usually the language of the application is set from the language of the system (in phone settings), that's how most iPhone apps operate. If you go with that route - you get 'locale switching' for free, and `NSLocalizedString` method takes care of picking correct strings for you.

Comment: See also: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1